# React: How to show loading on table every time I submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react-Flask app that you add an input and it will load a table based on the input.

The first search I do when the page loads it shows my loading circles perfectly fine and makes the API call and loads my data all fine.
But when I hit the search button again to search for something different I still see the same table and it doesn't show the loading circles again.
The API call is working fine in the back end and I at some point I get the new result back, but for a user, it will not know that the back end is running and it will look confusing, I want to make sure they know its loading.

How can I make it so that it shows the loading circles every time I hit the search button?

Here is my code:

```js
class Home extends Component {

// This is to make the table appear when clicking
// Setting state false so that it doesnt appear
constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.state = { showMessage: false }
  }

  _showMessage = (bool) => {
    this.setState({
      showMessage: bool
    });
  }

  

//Input sending data and Calling API back
  state ={
  data: []
}
//this gets triggered on line 85
  search = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Here we send the input that we add on line 90 value to Flask
    axios.post("/results",{search_question: document.getElementById("buscar").value})
    //Then we call it back
    .then((res) => {
      // console.log(res.data)
      //We create data variable with our returned data
      const data = res.data
      //Empty variable to pass all values from data
      const question = []
      // for loop that goes into data and pused everything to questions variable.
      for(var i in data)
        {question.push(data[i])}
      //console log to make sure our API returned the correct data and we saved in question
      console.log(question)
      //creating the state of paa and selecting the second index in question
      this.setState({paas:question[1]})

    })
     

    }


}


  render() {


    //empty variable and set is a state
    const{paas = []} = this.state


    return (
  <div className="demo">
      
   
          <div className="Search"> 
            <form onSubmit={this.search}  method="post">
                  <p>
                  <div className="searchbar">
                    <div className="form__group field">
                       <div className="searchbox">
                          <input type="input" class="form__field" placeholder="Search" id='buscar' required />
                           <label for="name" class="form__label">E.g Food delivery</label>
                    </div>
                        <div className="button">

                           <AwesomeButton
                           //useless button that waits 15 seconds
                              type="primary"
                              size="medium"
                              action={this._showMessage.bind(null, true)}> Search 
                            </AwesomeButton>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </p>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>


{this.state.showMessage &&(
   <Container>
     <Legend />

  
     <Table>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>Sentiment</th>
                        <th>Magnitude</th> 
               
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                {paas.length ? paas.map(paa => (
                    <tr>
                      <td key="Questions">{paa.Questions}</td> 
                      <td key="Sentiment" >{paa.Sentiment}</td>
                      <td key="Magnitude"> {paa.Magnitude}</td>
                    </tr>
                   
                  ))
                :
                (<tr><td><Loading /> </td>
                 <td><Loading /> </td>
                 <td><Loading /> </td> </tr>)
                      }
                       </tbody>
                 </Table>
                 <CSVLink data={paas}>
                 <AwesomeButton
                  size="large"
                  type="secondary">
                  Download Data
                </AwesomeButton>
                 </CSVLink>
                  </Container>) 
}

<Content/>
  
  </div>
    
        
    );
  }
}
```

I tried adding a setTimeout() on showMessage but the It will make all my table dissapear.

Comment: You could have `isLoading` state, that when you submit the form it's set to `true` - then when your API request is resolved you set that back to `false`. Then use that `state` to display/hide the loading icon/message.

Comment: Many examples if you google react loader , this is a good one : https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/react-loading-screen-tactics-improving-user-experience-9452f183c00b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a boolean flag to show the state of table is loading or not. Your state should be something like this:

```
this.state ={
  showMessage: false
  isLoading:false
}
```

and your search function:

```
e.preventDefault();
 this.setState({isLoading:true})
    axios.post("/results",{search_question: document.getElementById("buscar").value})
    .then((res) => {
      const data = res.data
      const question = []
      for(var i in data)
        {question.push(data[i])}
   
      console.log(question)
      this.setState({paas:question[1],isLoading:false})
      })
```

As you can see, everytime your search function will be called, loading becomes **true** and after fetching api we set it to **false**
Only thing you should do is to check if **isLoading** is true, render yoyr loading indicator